# Android Cannot resolve symbol error in View.java

Tags: android, android-studio, android-view

I'm wondering something about View.java file.

In the java file, almost lines show **Cannot resolve symbol** error like below.

[image]

Why?

I know they work well though they show me error.

Is it bug of Android Studio? or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Edit : I found something weird.

[image]

They are in android.util package, But can not import some of them.

Comment: I got this most of time, very anoying. What i did mostly are:
1. Try to clean > rebuild project
2. Try to invalid cache and restart 
3. Update build tools
4. Update android studio 

You can give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried them all. But does not work for me.

Comment: I put additional image for details.